# rethinkdb: "RqlRuntimeError: Array over size limit" even when using limit()

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm trying to access a constant number of the latest documents of a table ordered by a "date" key. Note that the date, unfortunately, was implemented (not by me...) such that the value is set as a string, e.g "2014-01-14", or sometimes "2014-01-14 22:22:22". I'm getting a `"RqlRuntimeError: Array over size limit 102173"` error message when using the following query:

```
r.db('awesome_db').table("main").orderBy(r.desc("date"))
```

I tried to overcome this problem by specifying a constant limit, since for now I only need the latest 50:

```
r.db('awesome_db').table("main").orderBy(r.desc("date")).limit(50)
```

Which ended with the same error. So, my questions are:

1. How can I get a constant number of the latest documents by date?
2. Is ordering by a string based date field possible? Is this issue has something to do with my first question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get an error here is that the `orderBy` gets evaluated before the `limit` so it orders the entire table in memory which is over the array limit. The way to fix this is by using and index. Try doing the following:

```
table.indexCreate("date")
table.indexWait()
table.orderBy({index: r.desc("date")}).limit(50)
```

That should be equivalent to what you have there but uses an index so it doesn't require loading the entire table into memory.

Comment: This did not help, I already had the index created, still the same error. Raising array_limit helps.

Answer (score 1):

This code is decision problem.

ro:= r.RunOpts{ArrayLimit: 500000}
r.DB("wrk").Table("log").Run(sessionArray[0],**ro**)

Answer (score 0):

// This code for Python 
r.db('awesome_db').table("main").run(sesion, r.runOpts{arrayLimit: 500000})