# How can I get rows between dates in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102344/rethinkdb-rqlruntimeerror-array-over-size-limit-even-when-using-limit), I'm getting the latest rows out of my table by indexing the 'date' field and querying like this:

```
table.orderBy({index: r.desc("date")})
```

How can I filter between dates if the 'date' values are implemented as strings (e.g "2013-12-31" or "2013-12-31 22:22:22")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to do this is called `between` you can use it like so:

```
table.between(date1, data2).orderBy(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add the index as well, like: table.between(date1, date2, {index: "date"}) @Joe Doliner